# Check/uncheck all check box and add/subtract values

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In this piece of code in Java, I made several Check Boxes for colors, each CheckBox containing values.
When a user clicks on the CheckBox, the code automatically adds the total values ​​that each CheckBox contains. However, whenever a user deselects a CheckBox, please, how do you get the system to automatically decrease the total amount?
The system does not automatically decrease when you deselect the checkbox.
My code is:

```
public void calculateResult(View v) {
    int result = 0;
    int finalResult;

    if (red.isChecked()) {
        result += 10;
  } if (blue.isChecked()) {
        result += 10;
  } if (yellow.isChecked()) {
        result += 10;
  } if (green.isChecked()) {
        result += 20;
  } if (black.isChecked()) {
        result += 20;
  } if (white.isChecked()) {
        result += 20;
  } if (orange.isChecked()) {
        result += 30;
  } if (purple.isChecked()) {
        result += 30;
  } if (gray.isChecked()) {
        result += 30;
    }
    finalResult = result;
    
    if(finalResult > 0 && finalResult <= 60) {
        finalResultText.setText("Low Result");

    } else if(finalResult > 60 && finalResult <= 120) {
        finalResultText.setText("Medium Result");

    } else if (finalResult > 120 && finalResult <= 180) {
        finalResultText.setText("High Result");
    }
}
```

If you try to place, for example:

```
if (red.setSelected(false)) {
    result -= 10;
}
```

will point out the an error that needs the result of the method setSelected must be a Boolean value, while I want the total value to be a void type, since I would like to print a result on the screen later.

Comment: when is `calculateResult()` invoked?  That is when your score will be updated. If you need that method to run upon a click, then you need to use a click listener.

Comment: a method like `red.setSelected(false)` will (or should) perform the action of setting 'red' to false. It can't and shouldn't be used as a way to check the state of red.

Comment: There is a piece of code that calls the calculateResult () method.

However, when a user clicks the checkbox, the code automatically adds up the total value. But when you deselect a checkbox, it should automatically decrease the value, but it doesn't.

What code should you put in to decrease the total value?

For example, the code:

if (!red.isChecked ()) {
result -= 10;
}
It doesn't work properly.

Comment: 1. Tag your question. 2. You are using a setter in an if condition, was that intended? 3. Is selected and checked the same property. 4. Are you using some UI library? How do you attach calculateResult as a handler to checkbox click?

Comment: The code you should put in is to use "the piece of code that calls the calculateResult() method" into whatever listens to deselecting.

Comment: Can you show your method which invokes the calculateResult() method ?

Comment: The code is being made in Android Studio, inside a file called Calc:

    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById (R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext (), Calc.class);
                startActivity (intent);
            }
        });
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
if(red.isSelected() == false)  // or !red.isSelected()
    result -= 10;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tryed this, but it does not work, because to the 
code that you wrote, before starting to check CheckBoxes, all Check Boxes are unselected. So it's like the code calculates the result as negative. That is, there is a total value that starts with zero. Since all checkboxes start unchecked, then the code automatically decreases the total value to a negative number. As you check the checkboxes, they go up. But that is not the intention.
The intention is to decrease the CheckBox values ​​only after they are selected.

Answer (score 0):

I think assigning -10 to an unchecked box is NOT what you want to do. This would only work if the box has previously given 10 points, and that you never run the calculateResult() again (since if you run your calculateResult, you want to probably assign 0 points to the unchecked boxes and +points to the checked boxes.)

You say that checkedBoxes runs immediately when a box is selected and updates the score. Whatever mechanism you are using to run the checkedBoxes method (like a click listener, or OnSelect or something), you should be using a similar listener for when the box is unchecked (or better yet, on every click, run the score calculator).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't repeat yourself ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)). Make loop instead of manual written `if`s.
Secondly, divide code into methods. Each method should has only one resposibility.

1. Make global variable which will hold your checkboxes:

   `private List<Checkbox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<>();`
2. Make method to init your `checkboxes` variable:

   ```
   private void initCheckboxes() {
       checkboxes.add(red);
       checkboxes.add(blue);
       checkboxes.add(yellow);
       checkboxes.add(green);
       checkboxes.add(black);
       checkboxes.add(white);
       checkboxes.add(orange);
       checkboxes.add(purple);
       checkboxes.add(gray);
   }
   ```

or shorter version:

```
this.checkboxes = Arrays.asList(red, blue, yellow, green, black,
                                 white, orange, purple, gray);
```

3. Assign weights (scores) to your checkboxes:

   ```
   public int getCheckboxWeight(Checkbox checkbox) {
       if (checkbox.equals(red) || checkbox.equals(blue) || checkbox.equals(yellow)) {
           return 10;
       }

       if (checkbox.equals(green) || checkbox.equals(black) || checkbox.equals(white)) {
           return 20;
       }

       if (checkbox.equals(orange) || checkbox.equals(purple) || checkbox.equals(gray)) {
           return 30;
       }

       throw new IllegalArgumentException();
   }
   ```
4. Compute result:

   ```
   public void calculateResult(View v) {
       int result = 0;

       for (Checkbox checkbox : checkboxes) {
           if (checkbox.isChecked()) {
               result += getCheckboxWeight(checkbox);
           }
       }

       if (result <= 60) {
           finalResultText.setText("Low Result");
       } else if (result <= 120) {
           finalResultText.setText("Medium Result");
       } else if (result <= 180) {
           finalResultText.setText("High Result");
       }
   }
   ```
5. Call `calculateResult` from checkChanged checkbox listener.

Comment: His problem is that the result is calculated immediately upon a click that selects a box but that it does not update the score immediately upon de-selecting a checkbox. While your design is much more useful than his, it doesn't address the issue at hand.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. It is another excellent way to write this code.
And that's exactly what JimN wrote:
There are values ​​in each Checkbox. Each time a user clicks on a CheckBox, the value contained in a CheckBox automatically increases, and in the end it adds up.

The problem is that when a user deselects a CheckBox, the value of the unchecked CheckBox should automatically decrease in a total value, which I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way around this problem. If a user selects a wrong checkbox, simply click on a button to reset. This reset button calls the recreate() method, which resets. Thank you very much anyway.